# Theorem environment counter incrementing section/subsection counter

Tags: sectioning, counters, newtheorem

I have the following theorem environment's set up:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % Defined mdtheoremenv used below

% I don't believe this affects anything with numbering, including just in case
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thmt@listnumwidth{4.3em}
\makeatother

\newmdtheoremenv[...]{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newmdtheoremenv[...]{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} % shares counter with theorem
\newmdtheoremenv[...]{proposition}[subsection]{Proposition} % Proposition environment

\theoremstyle{definition} % This style is typically used for definitions, examples, etc.
\newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definition} % Numbered by subsection
```

However, it seems that the section counters are being incremented each time I use a theorem environment. For instance, in section 2.1, I declare three lemmas: Lemma 2.2.1, Lemma 2.2.2, and Lemma 2.2.3, which seems to consequently increase the section counter to 4 (?) Obviously, this is not very intuitive. Section 2.1 should be followed by section 2.2, not 2.3. How can I fix this?

**Section 2 Minimal Code**

```
\section{Sequences} % Correctly labeled as section 2

\subsection{Convergence} % Correctly labeled as section 2.1

\begin{itemize}
    \item[]
          \begin{definition}[Sequential convergence] % Labeled as Definition 2.2
              A sequence of real numbers ...
          \end{definition}
    \item[]
          \begin{lemma} % Labeled as Lemma 2.2.1
              A sequence of real numbers has \textbf{at most} one limit.
          \end{lemma}
    \item[]
          \begin{lemma} % Labeled as Lemma 2.2.2
              Every convergent sequence is bounded.
          \end{lemma}
    \item[]
          \begin{definition}[Sequential monotonicity] % Labeled as Definition 2.3
              A sequence $\seq{x}{n}$ is said to be ...
          \end{definition}
    \item[]
          \begin{lemma} % Labeled as Lemma 2.3.1
              Any increasing sequence that is bounded above is convergent.
          \end{lemma}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Algebraic Manipulations of Limits} % Incorrectly labeled as 2.4
```

**Actual Sectioning Output**:
[image: Table of Contents with issue displayed]

**Edit**: In editing my original question, I caught my silly mistake of using the subsection counter for my "Definition" environment. Changing that to "theorem" fixed the issue. Thanks for the help, anyways!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does another part of your code, currently not shown, modify `\thesection` and/or `\thesubsection`? If so, how?

Comment: Could you turn your code into a minimal example that shows your output?  We don't need all the spacing options.  We do need to see how you've defined things.

Comment: "I don't believe this affects anything." Please check for yourself.  And please provide a complete example that starts with the `documentclass`, goes through `\end{document}`, and has the `\section`, `\lemma`, `\lemma`, `\section` leading to the unwanted numbering.

Comment: From your final edit, it appears that David Carlisle was correct with his answer, and that the problem was that you had intervening definitions, not intervening lemmas.  If this is not correct, please let us know and provide a MWE that we can copy and paste to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not said how you defined `\newmdtheoremenv` but assuming it follows the same conventions as `\newtheorem`

`{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]`   means the `theorem` counter will reset every `subsection`

but

`{proposition}[subsection]{Proposition}` means that `proposition` shares the same counter as `subsection`  so will be numbered in the same sequence.

Note the position of the optional argument.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But why is the theorem/prop/lemma counter affecting the section counter? For instance, in section 2.1, I define two lemmas which consequently become Lemma 2.2.1, Lemma 2.2.2, and Lemma 2.2.3, respectively. Then, when I subsequently go to make a new subsection, it is labeled as section 2.4.

Comment: @codeing_monkey you need to show a full minimal example that displays that behaviour

Comment: @codeing_monkey I doubt theorem does that, but as I show you have specified that propositions use the subsection counter so it will go subsection 2.1  proposition 2.2 subsection 2.3.